# I am unable to use PhoneAuthOptions with Firebase in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
    targetCompatibility 1.8
}

compileSdkVersion 32
buildToolsVersion "33.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
    applicationId "com.pratapbrothers.jnvsocialconnection"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 32
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}


buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6'
    implementation 'io.github.chaosleung:pinview:1.4.4'

    // Firebase
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.3')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx'
}
```

here are the codes I am using to import the Database

```
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private DatabaseReference userDatabaseRef;
private StorageReference userProfileImageRef;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_details);

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Set up you account");

    initialize();

    customProgressDialog = new CustomProgressDialog(this);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentUserId = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    userProfileImageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profile images");
    userDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserId);

    )
)
```

There is also the same error in

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
```

--------- beginning of crash

```
    2023-03-22 14:19:07.621 3181-3181/com.pratapbrothers.jnvsocialconnection E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.pratapbrothers.jnvsocialconnection, PID: 3181
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pratapbrothers.jnvsocialconnection/com.pratapbrothers.jnvsocialconnection.OtpActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: null reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3735)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3903)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2328)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:255)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8212)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:632)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null reference
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthOptions$Builder.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.3.2:2)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.3.2:27)
    at com.pratapbrothers.jnvsocialconnection.OtpActivity.sendVerificationCode(OtpActivity.java:79)
    at com.pratapbrothers.jnvsocialconnection.OtpActivity.onCreate(OtpActivity.java:55)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8151)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8135)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3704)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3903) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2328) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:255) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8212) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:632) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049) 
    2023-03-22 14:19:07.638 3181-3181/com.pratapbrothers.jnvsocialconnection         I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3181 SIG: 9
```

Here is the OtpActivity.java

```
package com.pratapbrothers.jnvsocialconnection;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.chaos.view.PinView;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
public class OtpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView textSub, textError;
private PinView pinView;
private Button verifyButton;

private String phoneNumber, verificationId;

private CustomProgressDialog customProgressDialog;

private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private PhoneAuthOptions phoneAuthOptions;

private void initialize() {
    textSub = findViewById(R.id.textSub);
    textError = findViewById(R.id.textError);
    pinView = findViewById(R.id.pinView);
    verifyButton = findViewById(R.id.verifyButton);
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_otp);

    initialize();

    phoneNumber = getIntent().getStringExtra("phone_number");

    sendVerificationCode(phoneNumber);

    customProgressDialog = new CustomProgressDialog(this);

    textError.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    pinView.requestFocus();

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Verify your phone number");

    textSub.setText("Enter the 6-digit OTP sent to your phone number " + phoneNumber + " to verify");


    verifyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            verifyCode(pinView.getText().toString());
        }
    });

}


private void sendVerificationCode(String number) {
    PhoneAuthOptions options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(firebaseAuth)
                    .setPhoneNumber(number)
                    .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .setActivity(this)
                    .setCallbacks(new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String s, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                            verificationId = s;
                            Toast.makeText(OtpActivity.this, "OTP sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {

                            final String code = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();

                            if (code != null) {
                                pinView.setText(code);
                                verifyCode(code);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {

                        }
                    })
                    .build();

    PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);
}


private void verifyCode(String code) {
    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);
    signInWithCredential(credential);
}


private void signInWithCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(OtpActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(OtpActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

**here is my question in brief**

Actually i am making an app like social media, here i am using phone number login option to let my user login with phone number and storing their data like-name, DOB, gender, job etc on theDatabase.

Everything was going good in the initials, even database was also working everything was working properly, but when i was there to implement phone number login method it required a class called as **PhoneAuthOptions**  and this class was not available in firebase library.
I search the error on the internet and found that i should use firebase bom and when i used this it made it, but it also made the error for database.

I have to use both the libraries (Phone number login, Database) in my app

Answer (score 0):

[PhoneAuthOptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/PhoneAuthOptions) class exists inside the [com.google.firebase.auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/package-summary) package. So if you want to use that dependency inside your Android app, I recommend you use the following lines of code:

```
implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.3")
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx"
```

For the other Firebase services, please add the following dependencies:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx"
```

In the case of using BOM, there is no need to specify the versions anymore. If you're using Java, then you can omit `-ktx` from the above lines.

Comment: No, it doesn't solved.
When using bom ( even after using your codes) it makes DatabaseReference, FirebaseDatabase etc red, means it gives error that "Can not resolve symbol".

Comment: After adding the above dependencies, have added the proper imports inside your classes? For example, for the DatabaseReference, have you added `import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference`?

Comment: yes, i have added proper imports for each library

Comment: I am just unable to add Database, either it is Database Reference or Firebase Database

Comment: Please edit your question and add the content of your build.gradle files and the code that you're using for imports.

Comment: Please read the question again

Comment: Aren't you using any package? I only see the imports without any package name.

Comment: There is package name, i have just not shown in this code

Comment: hey, i made it, I just used firebaseAuth version 19.3.2 and database version 19.6.0 and it worked.

Now i have PhoneAuthOptions class and DataBase also

Comment: using these versions made me to use the code but now using these codes gives an crash to my app when these codes are executed.
and also firebase storage gives an crash

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: Changing the Firebase Storage version worked for storage but now for PhoneAuthOptions, it is crashing the app.

Read the question again for logcat.

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting NullPointerException?

Comment: `at com.pratapbrothers.jnvsocialconnection.OtpActivity.sendVerificationCode(OtpActivity.java:79)`


this line of logcat indicates to the code

`PhoneAuthOptions options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(firebaseAuth)`

Comment: That's not a problem regarding dependencies, which actually seems to be solved. That's a NullPointerException that is thrown because you're calling a method on a null object reference. If you have any other issue that derives from the one that is already solved, then it's considered a new question and should be added separately. So please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Can I help you with other information regarding the initial issue?

Comment: i got the solution, it was a very small mistake, i wasn't called the instance of firebase auth.
now everything is alright.